# Adding a TextBox dynamically based on bool

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Case is an MVC 5 application

I have a class Team (sports team), that looks like this:

```
public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string Badge { get; set; }
        public TeamColor? TeamColor { get; set; }
        public League? League { get; set; }
        public bool HasAlias { get; set; }
        public bool IsAlias { get; set; }
        public int? AliasId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team AliasTeam { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Team> Aliases  { get; set; }
    }
```

An AliasTeam is a Team with just a TeamName an AliasId.

How do I go about adding a textbox for filing out the AliasTeamName if the user has clicked the HasAlias checkbox on the original team, and how do I loop through the textboxes in the controller in order to add them as Teams with an AliasId of the original team?

Controller action looks like this right now, where I can add a Team

```
 public ActionResult CreateTeam(CreateTeamViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var team = new Team
                {
                    TeamName = model.TeamName,
                    TeamColor = model.TeamColor,
                    League = model.League
                };
                db.Teams.Add(team);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("AddTeamImage", new {teamid = team.Id});
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

EDIT:

Solved it by adding following js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#HasAlias").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(".textboxes").append('<div><input class="form-control text-box single-line" placeholder="enter aliasname" type="text" name="teams"/><a href="#" class="add_field"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a><a href="#" class="remove_field"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></a></div>');
            } else {
                $(".textboxes").empty();
            }
        });
            $('.textboxes').on("click", ".add_field", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".textboxes").append('<div><input class="form-control text-box single-line" placeholder="enter aliasname" type="text" name="teams"/><a href="#" class="add_field"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a><a href="#" class="remove_field"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></a></div>');
            });
            $('.textboxes').on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
            });
        });
```

And then looping through array of teams in Action:

```
public ActionResult CreateTeam(CreateTeamViewModel model, string[] teams)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var team = new Team
                {
                    TeamName = model.TeamName,
                    TeamColor = model.TeamColor,
                    League = model.League,
                    HasAlias = model.HasAlias
                };
                db.Teams.Add(team);
                db.SaveChanges();
                foreach (var s in teams)
                {
                    var t = new Team
                    {
                        TeamName = s,
                        AliasId = team.Id,
                        IsAlias = true
                    };
                    db.Teams.Add(t);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

I may have misunderstood the whole ViewModel paradigm then. I thought you where meant to create ViewModels, with only the information needed to create a result.

Comment: First of all, why don't you have a ´Team´ instance in your ´CreateTeamViewModel´ - then you could post that in the form - by model binding you would not have to manually populate the `Team` in the action. And about the alias textbox appearing, you should always have it in your form as hidden, and use javascript to make it show depending on the value of the checkbox.

Comment: ToaoG is right, model binding will do this for you by default - thats what so great about it, and yes it will handle complex objects and their composite members. I suggest you use the automatic scaffolding feature in VS to create a new view based on the CreateTeamViewModel which i assume mirrors underlying EF model. And then take a look at what it produces and play around with postback to get an idea of whats going on. Basically at this point you are handcoding things which are by and large automatic.